# Android display progressdialog while loading URLs

Tags: java, android, dialog, load

My problem is really weird. The scenario is pretty simple: I wan't to show a progress Dialog as long as my activity is loading urls contents.

First I've tried to display a ProgressDialog just on its own, without any special functions inside. Worked well. But as soon as I added a function which loads urls, the program first loaded those urls and then displayed the progress bar. Here's my code:

```
progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
progDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
progDialog.show();

client = new GameClient(context, universe, username, password);
client.login();

progDialog.dismiss();
```

Nothing special. But for some reason the activity first make the "login-part" and then tries to show the dialog, but it doesn't show up anyhow ...

Could you give me hints to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ProgressDialog Class to show it.

```
/*****************************************
 * AsyncTask Class to Parse and Display
 ******************************************/
class AsyncTaskClassName extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    /* ***********************************
     * Pre-Execute Method 
     * ********************************** */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = util.getProgressDialog(ActivityClassName.this, "Please wait...", "Parsing List...    ");
           //ActivityClassName -> The Name of the Activity Class you want to show ProgressDialog
        // progressDialog.hide();
        progressDialog.show();

        /* Do your Pre-Execute Configuration */
    }

    /* ***********************************
     * Execute Method 
     * ********************************** */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        /* Do yourxec Task ( Load from URL) and return value */
        return null;
    }

    /* ***********************************
     * Post-Execute Method 
     * ********************************** */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    /* Do your Post -Execute Tasks */
    }
```

Comment: This question is old, but still u did your best, thanks :) This will definately solve the problem aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the login in a separate Thread so it doesn't block the UI thread, like this

```
...
progDialog.show();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        client = new GameClient(context, universe, username, password);
        client.login();

        progDialog.dismiss();
    }
}).start();
```

or use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). See http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Hm, thanks, already got that idea but ive coded it the wrong way. Thanks :)